# how to restrict google map api to find places within a specific country and city both?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have search lot many sites but didn't find anything related to the same . I'll be great thankful if someone helps me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [component filters](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/?hl=cs#ComponentFiltering). That will do your task.

But it has limitation. you could restrict only one country at a time( you cant restrict with multiple country, But you can trigger it out in some other ways)

[Demo](http://jsbin.com/vayohizu/1/edit) . The demo is self explanatory. In the demo, You can only find the places in `INDIA` at the text box (You cant find other places in the world).